# PayPal - received cancel but the transaction was succesfull

Tags: paypal, checkout

On an e-commerce site in the payment page I used the new js sdk from paypal.

When the user clicks on paypal button a popup appears and the user performs the transaction in the popup.

When the transaction is over the popup closes and a callback is called to do what is needed.

If the user manually closes the popup, a CANCEL event is emitted and the transaction is considered canceled.

The problem I'm having is that sometimes I see on the logs that I receive the CANCEL event (meaning that the user has closed the popup) but on PayPal account the transaction is succesfull and correctly payed...

Is it possible that the user closes the popup just before paypal sends the confirmation back or something like that? Anyone knows how this can be handled?

Answer (score 0):

Using the JS SDK alone is for very simple use cases. For an ecommerce site of any importance, the JS SDK should be combined with the v2/checkout/orders API. This way orders are always captured from the server and recorded when successful, and things happening on the client side won't be relevant nor interfere with accurate payment tracking.

Your question doesn't give technical details for your current integration, but here's how to go about making a correct one from scratch:

---

Use the v2/checkout/orders API and make two routes (url paths) on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'. You could use one of the (recently deprecated) Checkout-*-SDKs for the routes' API calls to PayPal, or your own HTTPS implementation of first getting an access token and then doing the call. Both of these routes should return/output **only** JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should verify the amount was correct and store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as reserving product or sending an email) immediately *before* forwarding return JSON to the frontend caller. In the event of an error forward the JSON details of it as well, since the frontend must handle such cases.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  (If you need to send any additional data from the client to the server, such as an items array or selected options, add a `body` parameter to the fetch with a value that is a JSON string or object)

Comment: Thankyou for the answer but I'm afraid this does not resolve the issue. The frontend approval described by you applies when the "onApprove"  callback is called, but this callback is NOT called by the system. What happens, only sometimes,  (and I can only detect this by my logs) is that only the "onCancel" callback is called by the system (it happens when the user closes the popup) even if on PayPal side the transaction is succesfull... I'm wondering how this can happen...